# How to get AEM 6.3 to Livereload clientlibs

Tags: gulp, aem, livereload

I am using the gulp-aemsync plugin to sync my css and js changes to a clientlib on an AEM instance. A have a gulp task watching the js and css that runs gulp-aemsync fine (changes are on the site when i refresh), but being a bit lazy as i am it would be nice to get live reload working so that i never have to manually refresh the page while working.

I have tried to follow both these 2 online guides:

https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/live-reload/index.html

https://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/cq/up-and-running-with-livereload-in-adobe-aem6

Followed the steps of:

- installing Netty package on AEM instance
- installing ACS AEM tools package on the AEM instance
- installing the RemoteLiveReload chrome extension (the AEM instance is hosted on AWS)

That didn't work, so i got one of our DevOps engineers to open port 35729 (which is the default for Livereload) on the AEM instance. That still doesn't work, and when i click the chrome browser extension to sync it i get the following message:

**Could not connect to LiveReload server. Please make sure that LiveReload 2.3 (or later) or another compatible server is running.**

Can anyone help me figure this out as i'd really like to get it working to streamline my workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **DISCLAIMER:** This answer is based on a setup I had working at some point, and by no means is a complete/working answer. But it should give you an alternative to the other tools that exist and get you half way there.

I have not used the tools you are mentioning, but since you are using gulp and aemsync, you ***could*** do the following:

In your gulp setup, create a websocket server and basically make that server publish messages everytime aemsync is triggered to push content to AEM.

```
// start a websocket server
const WebSocket = require('ws'); // requires "npm install ws"
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8081 });
const connections = [];
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  connections.push(ws); // keep track of all clients

  // send any new messages that come to this server, to all connected clients
  ws.on('message', (d) => connections.forEach(connection => connection.send(d)));
});

// create a new websocket to send messages to the websocket server above
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

// send a regex to the server every second
// NOTE: CHANGE this to run when aemsync is triggered in your build 
setInterval( () => ws.send('reload'), 1000 );
```

Then in your JS code (on AEM) or really in a `<script>` tag that you make sure will NOT go beyond your local (or dev/prod) you can setup a websocket listener to refresh the page:

```
socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');
socket.onopen  = // add function for when ws is open
socket.onclose  = // add function for when ws is closed
socket.onerror = // add function for when ws errors
// listen to messages and reload!
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  location.reload();
});
```

**Alternatively**, you could use the chrome plugin I've developed:
https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/websocket-refresh-chrome-ext

It's not perfect by any means. However, for a basic setup, it should work great! an you don't need to touch your AEM JS.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, i have created a websocket server to send a reload command to the browser window as you suggested. It worked just fine. For anyone trying to do this using AEM ACS commons live reload package, forget it - it doesn't work!